# Attempting to compare two arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to create a program that simulates the lottery. I create my first array with 6 random numbers and then attempt to keep populating my second array with random numbers until they aare the same. It works when the numbers are between 1 and 9 but when I extend it to between 1 - 49 like the real lottery i just get a time out.

```
<?php 

    $number1 = $_POST['number1'];
    $number2 = $_POST['number2'];
    $number3 = $_POST['number3'];
    $number4 = $_POST['number4'];
    $number5 = $_POST['number5'];
    $number6 = $_POST['number6'];


$userArray = array($number1, $number2, $number3, $number4, $number5, $number6);


// mix and max numbers that can be used with th lottery
$min = 1;
$max = 49;
// random number between 0 and 1 simulating lottery

    $lotNumber1 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber2 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber3 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber4 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber5 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber6 = rand ($min, $max);

$lotArray = array($lotNumber1, $lotNumber2, $lotNumber3, $lotNumber4, $lotNumber5, $lotNumber6);

asort($userArray);
asort($lotArray);

$userString = implode($userArray, "_"); 
$lotString = implode($lotArray, "_");


$i = 0;

set_time_limit(10000);

while($lotString != $userString) {

    $i ++;

    $lotNumber1 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber2 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber3 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber4 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber5 = rand ($min, $max);
    $lotNumber6 = rand ($min, $max);

    $lotArray = array($lotNumber1, $lotNumber2,             $lotNumber3, $lotNumber4, $lotNumber5, $lotNumber6);

    asort($lotArray);

    $lotString = implode($lotArray, "_");

}


echo '<pre>';
print_r ($lotString);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($userString);
echo '</pre>';

echo "YOU WON it took ".$i." times";


?>
```

Comment: first of all you are using implode in the wrong way `string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )` so in your case it will be `$userString = implode("_", $userArray);`, '_' being the glue ;)

Comment: and maybe you just didn't win - that's why it's called a lottery ;)

Comment: =)) good one... he's just out of luck :(

Comment: I will try that now Ares thanks

Comment: No problem ;) tell me if it works better

Comment: can I presume that this works? Since you didn't said anything more... :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lotNumber1 = rand ($min, $max);
$lotNumber2 = rand ($min, $max);
$lotNumber3 = rand ($min, $max);
$lotNumber4 = rand ($min, $max);
$lotNumber5 = rand ($min, $max);
$lotNumber6 = rand ($min, $max);
```

is a problem, you should use shuffle(range(1,49)) and take the first 6 to ensure no duplicates.

As the other answer suggests, its a big calculation, one in around 13 million. Thats a lot of loops making random numbers and sorting them, you will likely need a larger timeout that 30s

My code is

```
<?php

$number1 = 1;
$number2 = 2;
$number3 = 3;
$number4 = 4;
$number5 = 5;
$number6 = 6;


$userArray = array($number1, $number2, $number3, $number4, $number5, $number6);


// mix and max numbers that can be used with th lottery
$min = 1;
$max = 49;
// random number between 0 and 1 simulating lottery

$lotArray = (range($min,$max));

asort($userArray);


$userString = implode($userArray, "_");
$lotString = "";


$i = 0;

set_time_limit(10000);

while($lotString != $userString) {
  $i ++;
  shuffle($lotArray);

  $lotA = array_slice($lotArray,0,6);

  asort($lotA);

  $lotString = implode($lotA, "_");

}


echo '<pre>';
print_r ($lotString);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r ($userString);
echo '</pre>';

echo "YOU WON it took ".$i." times";


?>
```

`<pre>1_2_3_4_5_6</pre><pre>1_2_3_4_5_6</pre>YOU WON it took 12004536 times`

real    0m41.926s

Comment: Thank you for the help, still seems to timeout for me. I'll carry on trying!

Comment: My times are between 25 seconds and 7 minutes. It is a fairly large amount of calculation to do. Most defaults timeouts are 30 seconds. I run it though the command line to get times.